# Is it possible to have a variable height UIView mask layer NOT stretch, and perhaps just sit at the top? (For example, a "torn paper" style edge?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, calayer

I can't for the life of me figure out how to create such an effect on a UIView that has dynamic height. I want to have the top have a "torn paper" style edge, but the view can be of dynamic height, so when I set the torn paper mask at the top, it gets stretched the full length of the view.

Can I say, "stick to the top", or perhaps designate a portion that is supposed to stretch? Preferably with layers but iOS 8's `maskView` property works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the frame of the layer's mask to anything you want. So that's one way to position it.

Or you could (probably, I haven't tried yet) use a stretchable image view as the mask (- resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:). That should keep the torn paper edge from stretching.